# An error with a three dimensional field (of vectors) in rcpp armadillo

Tags: rcpp, armadillo

I am trying to create a field in rcpp arma due to more than three iterations, but got an error. As an example, see the following simple code:

```
//[[Rcpp::export]]
field<vec> testgg(int k, int h, int g){
  field<vec> res(k, h, g);
  return(res);
}
```

I do nothing in this code, so this code should give me something. However, I got an error when I do this function like this.

```
> testgg(3,4,5)
Error in testgg(3, 4, 5) : 
  dims [product 12] do not match the length of object [60]
> testgg(3,4,1)
     [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]     
[1,] numeric,0 numeric,0 numeric,0 numeric,0
[2,] numeric,0 numeric,0 numeric,0 numeric,0
[3,] numeric,0 numeric,0 numeric,0 numeric,0
```

My guess is that the rcpp does not get this three dimensional field, but can get the field up to 2 dimensions. Why does this happen and how can I get a three dimensional field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see the open issue [#263](https://github.com/RcppCore/RcppArmadillo/issues/263) and maybe also other ones.  There was a bug, there is a fix, but you currently need to set a `#define` to enable the fix (as we need to sort out if this has side-effects on other packages assuming the current behaviour).

So in short do for example

```
> Sys.setenv(PKG_CPPFLAGS="-DRCPP_ARMADILLO_FIX_Field")  ## sets #define RCPP_ARMADILLO_FIX_Field
> Rcpp::cppFunction("arma::field<arma::vec> testgg(int k, int h, int g) { arma::field<arma::vec> res(k, h, g); return(res);}", depends="RcppArmadillo")
> testgg(2,3,4)
, , 1

     [,1]      [,2]      [,3]     
[1,] numeric,0 numeric,0 numeric,0
[2,] numeric,0 numeric,0 numeric,0

, , 2

     [,1]      [,2]      [,3]     
[1,] numeric,0 numeric,0 numeric,0
[2,] numeric,0 numeric,0 numeric,0

, , 3

     [,1]      [,2]      [,3]     
[1,] numeric,0 numeric,0 numeric,0
[2,] numeric,0 numeric,0 numeric,0

, , 4

     [,1]      [,2]      [,3]     
[1,] numeric,0 numeric,0 numeric,0
[2,] numeric,0 numeric,0 numeric,0

>
```

So if you compile with the correct flag, the field dimension is not reduced down.

*Edit* And maybe you wanted `cube` instead of `field` ?

```
> Rcpp::cppFunction("arma::cube testhh(int k, int h, int g) { arma::cube res(k, h, g); return(res);}", depends="RcppArmadillo")
> testhh(4,3,2)
, , 1

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    0    0    0
[2,]    0    0    0
[3,]    0    0    0
[4,]    0    0    0

, , 2

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    0    0    0
[2,]    0    0    0
[3,]    0    0    0
[4,]    0    0    0

>
```

Comment: Thanks! It works now by putting "#define RCPP_ARMADILLO_FIX_Field" in my cpp source file. Thanks again!

Comment: Great!  Feel free to upvote the answer (click on up-triangle) and/or also accept it (click on tick-mark) which is the common way around StackOverflow to signal that an anwer was helpful.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know those functions. I am new to stack overflow. 

I have one more question. I usually wirte an R package collecting my rcpp functions to use those conveniently. When I use my rcpp function via source cpp file, your suggestion can solve my issue. However, when I create an R package with this source cpp file (of course, I put that line in my cpp file), this error appeared again. How can I solve this?

Comment: BTW, What I want is a field of cubes. The above code is just for a simple description of my problem. Just let you konw.

Comment: Please take a moment to learn about package for `Rcpp` ir `RcppArmadillo` -- the `Rcpparmadillo.package.skeleton()` function can help you.  You can declare the `#define` in each source file, a common header file, a `-D...` directive in `src/Makevars`, ...

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I looked at your pdf file "Writing a package that uses Rcpp". What do I need to write specifically in src/Makevars (or src/Makevar.win)? I do not understand your saying " `-D...` directive"

Comment: Standard use of `make` and its `Makefile` format and compiler switches.  Look for example [here](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/anytime/blob/278b645b81b45ef86dbb95eaf84b14c7436b0831/src/Makevars#L6) how `anytime sets a compilation flag/option .

Comment: Thanks! I added that line in Makevar files and this issue was gone! Thanks again, although I still do not understand all things perfectly.

Comment: I usally run my code on Linux, but this happened again in Linux (it does not happen in Windows on my laptop). How is this possible? How can I fix it?

Comment: There is always more to learn about packages. Windows has its own `src/Makevars.win` where you need to set it too.

Comment: I of course set it on `src/Makevars.win` as well as `src/Makevar`. The function in my package works in Windows but does not in Linux. Do I need to do something more to make it in Linux? What I understood is that I just need to fix that flag I encountered as you suggested in Makevar and/or Makevar.win, whatever OS I use.

Comment: There is a limit to what we can diagnose here in three line comments.  StackOverflow recommends [minimally complete verifiable examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) -- maybe you can edit your question, maybe you can ask a new one.  Good luck!

Comment: That is a good idea! Thank you for your suggestion!