# R package: Error appears not in Windows but in Linux

Tags: r, makefile, rcpp, r-package

guys.

I am currently trying to build an R package (using rcpp). By this [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71025971/an-error-with-a-three-dimensional-field-of-vectors-in-rcpp-armadillo/71026339?noredirect=1#comment125576363_71026339), I encountered an error, which was fixed by putting the following line in `src/Makevar` and/or `src/Makevar.win`.

`PKG_CXXFLAGS = -DRCPP_ARMADILLO_FIX_Field`

However, this error disappeared when I run my function in Windows on my laptop, but it again appeared in Linux. (I usually wirte the code in Windows on my laptop and run the code by using Linux for parallel computing provided by my university) It seems that that line can remove the flag in Windows but cannot remove it in Linux.

How can this happen, and how can I fix this?

Comment: This is not reproducible, If your code is on a public repo, include a link.

Comment: One guess:  Look closely at the output of the `R CMD INSTALL` lines on both. It could be that a different compiler on the different OS uses a _different C++ standard_ in which case you may need `PKG_CXX11FLAGS` or `PKG_CXX14FLAGS` or ...  You can also specificy the compilation standard to avoid this.  See the Writing R Extensions for all answers to your packaging questions :)

Comment: Thanks! I just updated RcppArmadillo in that Linux (from RcppArmadillo_0.10.6.0.0 
to RcppArmadillo_0.10.8.1.0), and this issue seems to be resolved! I really appreciate your help!

Comment: That would do it too.  A release before I added the hotfix won't have it :)